# Selenium automation with xpath for all browsers

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am new to selenium automation and I am trying to figure out how to handle the code for an element that shows different xpath for different browsers.

```
//xpath for IE
 private readonly By ByPermIE = By.XPath("//*[@id='group-permissions']/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]");

//xpath for chrome
 private readonly By ByPermChrome = By.XPath("//*[@id='group-permissions']/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]");
```

If I am performing some action on this element on different browsers how do I use these elements in the test case. I am planning to extend this to three more browsers. So, should I use if else conditions everywhere? Is there any alternate of best practice for such cases?

Comment: Can you post the HTML code ??

Comment: Probably sharing the HTML would help think about any other practice.

Comment: solution also depends how you have designed your automation framework if u have defined a method in your base class and calling that method in your test case (inheritance concept) then its good use if else on the basis of browser

Comment: This is a great use case for using CSS selectors instead of XPath.  If you show us the relevant HTML, we can probably recommend a CSS selector that would work for any browser.

Answer (score 2):

You can use below xpath for you case.

```
private readonly By ByPermChrome = By.XPath("//*[@id='group-permissions']/div[1]//span[text() = 'text that span contains']");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write xpath as relative as possible.It is not advisable to write absolute xpaths.

For your above case use below xpath which works in both the browsers.

```
By.XPath("//*[@id='group-permissions']//span[2]");
```

or

```
By.XPath("//*[@id='group-permissions']//span[text()='someThing']");
```

Refer [this](http://santoshsarmajv.blogspot.in/2013/09/locating-webelements-using-xpath.html) for more info regarding xpath.

Answer (score 0):

if u post ur html code, than it will be easy. But as there is no html given, i can suggest u a way like below:

```
//u can use if condition here
if(driver.findElements(By.XPath("//*[@id='group-permissions']/div[1]/div[2]/span[2]")).size()==1){

    //perform operation here
}

else
    //perform operation here
```

This is an alternative way as there is no html code.

If u give the html code, i think we can suggest u more be

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion I can give here is you can use OR conditions in xpaths. Say  OR  OR . 
Xpath OR returns successful as soon it hits the first correct one.